# Pathfinder favored class "using X level as Y level"

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, paladin, oracle, tiefling

I have a Tiefling Arcanist with Variant Multiclass Oracle with Merciful Curse. Part of the curse reads "You gain the ability to lay on hands, as the paladin ability, using your curse level as your paladin level."
And the racial Favored Class from Tiefling for paladins is "Add +1 to the amount of damage the paladin heals with lay on hands, but only when the paladin uses that ability on herself."

Without having actual "Paladin" levels, would I still be able to choose this and gain the benefit for this? Or does it have to be "real" levels only?

Answer (score 13):

You can't gain the favored class bonus unless you are taking a level in it. That means if if you have a level in Paladin and take levels in Oracle, you still cannot take the favored class bonus for Paladin, only Oracle.

The favored class ability does still apply to the Oracle's lay on hands however, if you had taken it before.

Comment: But if you had levels in both, and took the paladin favoured class bonus, it would apply to your Oracle Lay on hands as well.

Comment: That's true. I'll add that to the answer.